# How can I take a value from an item text in a data block and insert it into another item text of another data block? pl/sql oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

to not confuse anyone, my question is: 
I'm asking if this is the proper way to call a value of an item text and insert it into another value of another item text (in another block)?

for me  I think there's something missing I don't know where

I've two data blocks inside a single form

one block has been manually created (there's no table is associated with) named (`block15`) 
another block was built by the data wizard (named as the name of the DB table (`CRI_AV_VIEW`), it is a "view table".

well
this is the pl/SQL code of the button trigger `when_button_pressed` (the button is under the items of `block15`)

```
  --before you just start, suppose the inputs is like these - 
  --down bellow
  --don't worry, all of them are exists and true.

    --x1= 1005003000
    --x2= 6492 3684 3827 7890 (without spaces)
    --x3= 461 
    --x4= 4
    --x5= 200
    --x6= 4Y9MH
DECLARE
  x1         NUMBER(10):= :block15.item16;
  x2         NUMBER(16):= :block15.item20;
  x3         NUMBER(3):= :block15.item21;
  x4         NUMBER(3):= :block15.item32;
  x5         NUMBER(12,2):= :cri_av_view.cost_per_day;
  x6         VARCHAR2(32):= :cri_av_view.car_id;
  v_count1   NUMBER;
  v_count2   NUMBER;
  v_count3   NUMBER;
  time_1     DATE;
  time_2     DATE;
BEGIN
---FIRST---
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count1
  FROM citizens_lic
  WHERE id = x1;

  SELECT SYSDATE
  INTO time_1
  FROM dual;

---FIRST IF-----    
  IF(v_count1 = 1)THEN
---SEOND---
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_count2
    FROM citizens_lic
    WHERE id = x1
          AND work_status NOT IN(
      'STUDENT'
    );

----SECOND IF -----
    IF(v_count2 = 1)THEN
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO v_count3
      FROM client_accounts ca
      WHERE ca.card_num = x2
            AND ca.cvc = x3
            AND(exp_date > time_1)-- all of them are in date datatype
            AND(balance >(x4 * x5));--once the operation reached here, something wired is happened, x5 is like something big while in fact, it is less, this condition based on the given must be true and gives back only 1, (SQL plus command proved that for me)!

      IF(v_count3 = 1)THEN
---------- PRE-APPROVING THE TIME AND DATE FOR THE ORDER ------
        SELECT SYSDATE
        INTO time_2
        FROM dual;          

----------------- INSERT THE ORDER--------           
        INSERT INTO car_rent_orders(
          car_id,
          end_rent,
          customer_id,
          card_num,
          cvc
        )VALUES(
          x6,
          (time_2 + x4),
          x1,
          x2,
          x3
        );

        UPDATE car_rent_inv
        SET
          car_status = 0
        WHERE car_id = x6;

        message('THANK YOU FOR RENTING WITH US, PLEASE WAIT TO PRINT YOU COPY OF THE ORDER!');
        COMMIT;
      ELSE
        message('INSUFFCENT AMMOUNT IN YOUR CARD!');
        COMMIT;
      END IF;

    ELSE
      message('SORRY, YOUR WORK STATUS WON''T ALLOW YOU TO RENT A CAR!');
      COMMIT;
    END IF;

  ELSE
    message('SORRY, SEEMS LIKE YOU ARE NOT HAVING A CITIZENS'' LICENCE !');
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END;
```

well, although the code is already `compiled`, works fine, but it seems like nothing inside `x5`, that's why I'm getting the message (you have an insufficient amount in your card) but that's not true

does it ignore the x5??

I might have mistaken the way I've created both blocks, 
or maybe the `CRI_AV_VIEW` block have a `table view` so it won't give me any value,
or I might not know how to take a value of an `item textbox` and drive it into another value of another `item box`?

please guide me with your opinion 
we might save the day! 
or we might stack over the flow!

Comment: There's no "V5" in your code, so - why do you expect to see anything in it? By the way, what is "V5"? Also (not directly related to the question): I'd suggest you to give variables and items and columns *meaningful* names. Today you know what X3 is; tomorrow, you won't.

Comment: I'm sorry @Littlefoot , I swear all that I meant is to make a good question that is fully described :(, x5 not v5 edited.